# Is QED confining in 2+1 dimensions? Are there experimental realizations in condensed matter systems?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

In 1d, QED is confining because the potential is linear and it costs an infinite amount of energy to separate two equal and opposite charges. I am guessing that the same is true in 2d, since the potential is $\sim\ln \frac{r}{r_{0}}$, and in the limit of infinite separation of two equal and opposite charges, i.e. $r\rightarrow \infty$, the logarithmic potential goes to infinity. Is this interpretation correct? How does this manifest itself in condensed matter systems?